# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'short'

Tags: c#

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
    {       
        string kundeID = "-1";
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        int totalsum = Convert.ToInt32(ddlAmount.SelectedValue);

        Handlevogn handlevogn = new Handlevogn
        {
            TotalSum = totalsum,
            KundeID = kundeID,
            Dato = DateTime.Now,
            ErIHandlevogn = true,
            ProduktID = id
        };

        HandlevognModell modell = new HandlevognModell();
        lblResult.Text = modell.InsertHandlevogn(handlevogn);
    }
```

Keep getting the error

> Cannot implicitly convert typre 'string' to 'short'

for the local variable kundeID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to change your `kundelID` to `short`

```
short kundelID = -1;
```

Then your implicit conversion which you previously did here:

```
KundelID = kundelID; //this is called implicit because you implicitly tell kundelID, which is a short to be changed to KundelID, which is likely a short
```

Will be of the same type `short`.

Altrlernatively, if you need `kundelID` to be a `string` for whatever reason, convert it correctly to `KundelID` before it is used.

```
KundelID = Convert.ToInt16(kundelID);
```

Then, it will also be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function:

```
Int16.TryParse(string value, out number);
```

Who will return a boolean value, true if the function could cast it and false if not.

You can use it in an if:

```
short id;
if(Int16.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out id))
{
    ProduktID = id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is pretty verbose. You should parse kundeID into short (or change KundeID to be string).

```
KundeID = short.Parse(kundeID);
```

Answer (score -1):

If output is object covert to short can looks like that

```
short var_short = short.Parse(Convert.ToString(reader["something"]));
```